# Cramers rule and cross multiplying the matrix

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems

I am trying to recall math from many years ago (for me). I am trying to figure out how to multiply out the matrices for trilateration. If you could look here: https://www.ece.lsu.edu/scalzo/FDR_Final.pdf - on page 12, I am talking about `Equation 6` and `Equation 7` - the equations to get the coordinates.

My question is...how do I multiply the polynomials together correctly. Am I supposed to evaluate them how they are in their position, and then cross multiply the results? Or is it more complicated...like the opposite of factoring (again I'm hazy on my math). If you could provide an example for how to do one of the matrices that would be great. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Essentially, I want to know how to handle the multiplication like `(a-b)-(c-d)-(e-f) * 2(g-e)`...do I handle the 3 subtractions in parenthesis on the left side of the `*` before I multiply? or do I have to multiply the `2(g-e)` by each polynomial and factor in all of the signs?

Comment: These matrices seem to be three-by-three. For them,  you need something more elaborate than what you learned for two-by-two matrices. Look up “basket method” or “basket weaving method”. This is good for three-by-three matrices, but no bigger.

Comment: how are they 3 x 3? im talking about 2d trilateration...it looks like a 2x2 matrix / 2x2 matrix.....oh wait sorry..i listed the wrong page number...its page 12

Comment: Well, there seemed to be three independent variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially, I want to know how to handle the multiplication like `(a-b)-(c-d)-(e-f) * 2(g-e)`...do I handle the 3 subtractions in parenthesis on the left side of the `*` before I multiply? or do I have to multiply the `2(g-e)` by each polynomial and factor in all of the signs?

Either way, for example the numerator of $\,(6)\,$ is:

$$
\left|
\begin{matrix}
(a-b)-(c-d)-(e-f) & 2(g-h) \\
(a'-b')-(c'-d')-(e'-f') & 2(g'-h')
\end{matrix}
\right| \\[5px]
= \Big((a-b)-(c-d)-(e-f)\Big) \cdot 2(g'-h') - \Big((a'-b')-(c'-d')-(e'-f')\Big) \cdot 2(g-h) \\[5px]
= 2\,\Big((a-b)(g'-h')-(c-d)(g'-h')-(e-f)(g'-h')\Big) \\ \; -2\,\Big((a'-b')(g-h)-(c'-d')(g-h)-(e'-f')(g-h)\Big)
$$

Which one to choose depends on computational considerations rather than math ones.

Comment: interesting...what kind of computational considerations? would this difference matter for resources is an app?

Comment: @ewizard The raw number of multiplications is lower in the first form,
 for one thing. Then for example [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination), if some of the subexpressions happen to match between the different determinants. That could make a difference as far as performance goes, since compilers are usually conservative when optimizing floating point calculations.